# Assign Students a Grade and get totals for each Grade

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following select statement.  I have schools, courses, students and marks (1-100).  I want to assign a grade (A,B,C,D) and then get the total number of students in each grade.   My results only show the count of each mark though and not the count of the grade

```
select          
    schools.name as school_name,            
    courses.name as course,   
        CASE
             WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  > 79)
                  THEN 'A' 
                  WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  < 80) 
                         AND ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  >64)
                  THEN 'B' 
                  WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  < 80) 
                         AND ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  >64)
                  THEN 'C' 
                  WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  < 50)
                  THEN 'D'                         
          END as grade,             
    count(*)                 
from
    students,
    studentgrades,
    schools,
    courses
where
    studentgrades.studentid = students.studentid
    and studentgrades.schoolid = students.schoolid     
    and studentgrades.schoolid = schools.school_number 
    and courses.id = studentgrades.coursesid
    and studentgrades.averageScore is not null 
    and schools.name = 'St. Joe School'           
group by schools.name,  courses.name,standardsgrades.averageScore
```

What I get now is the count of individual marks (e.g. 5 students got 88%, 3 got 85% etc)

```
School Name     Course        Grade     Count        
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         5
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         3
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         2
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         1
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         1
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         2 
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         3
St. Joe School  MATH 30         B         2
St. Joe School  MATH 30         B         5
St. Joe School  MATH 30         B         2
St. Joe School  MATH 30         B         1 
St. Joe School  MATH 30         B         2
```

What I want to see it is the total of count of each grade (A,B,C,D)

```
School Name     Course        Grade     Count        
St. Joe School  MATH 30         A         30
St. Joe School  MATH 30         B         20
St. Joe School  MATH 30         C         10
St. Joe School  MATH 30         D         5
```

Comment: Why do Oracle users tend to use the old implicit joins?

Comment: It's some old code I'm trying to modify.  I usually use the explicit join ;)

Comment: Remove group by on `,standardsgrades.averageScore` and change `count(*)` to `count(*) Over (partition by {your case statement})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the calculated grade instead of the average score. You can do this using a CTE, subquery or repeating the whole expression in the group clause.

I find CTE based solution bit easy to read:

```
with cte
as (
    select schools.name as school_name,
        courses.name as course,
        case when ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50 * 100) > 79) then 'A' when ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50 * 100) < 80)
                and ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50 * 100) > 64) then 'B' when ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50 * 100) < 80)
                and ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50 * 100) > 64) then 'C' when ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50 * 100) < 50) then 'D' end as grade
    from students
    join studentgrades on studentgrades.studentid = students.studentid
        and studentgrades.schoolid = students.schoolid
    join schools on studentgrades.schoolid = schools.school_number
        and studentgrades.schoolid = schools.school_number
    join courses on courses.id = studentgrades.coursesid
    where studentgrades.averageScore is not null
        and schools.name = 'St. Joe School'
    )
select school_name,
    course,
    grade,
    count(*)
from cte
group by school_name,
    course,
    grade;
```

Also, *always* use modern *explicit* join syntax instead of the old comma based joins.

Comment: This is close but it is showing the count of the Grade column in the original table instead of the total count of the 'count' column.   So it's counting 7 Rows of  A's instead of  5+3+2+1+1+2+3= 17 

---------------------------------------------------------------
School Name     Course        Grade     Count  
      
St. Joe School MATH 30         A         7

Comment: @EvilEddie - your own sample data shows that it should be 17. Please add sample input data as well if you require any further help.

Comment: Sorry...the comment box doesn't allow for great formatting.    The correct result returned should be 17 (total of the  first 7 rows in the 4th column called Count)  but the result I am getting is 7 (total of the first 7 rows in the 3rd column called Grade).

Answer (score 0):

Put the query you have into a view and then query it with another GROUP BY and SUM.

```
SELECT SchoolName, Course, Grade, SUM(Count)
FROM YourNewView
GROUP BY SchoolName, Course, Grade
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do select on your existing query as like below:

```
select school_name, course,
grade,
sum(grade)
(select          
schools.name as school_name,            
courses.name as course,   
    CASE
         WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  > 79)
              THEN 'A' 
              WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  < 80) 
                     AND ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  >64)
              THEN 'B' 
              WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  < 80) 
                     AND ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  >64)
              THEN 'C' 
              WHEN   ((studentgrades.averageScore / 50  * 100)  < 50)
              THEN 'D'                         
      END as grade,             
count(*)                 
from
students,
studentgrades,
schools,
courses
where
studentgrades.studentid = students.studentid
and studentgrades.schoolid = students.schoolid     
and studentgrades.schoolid = schools.school_number 
and courses.id = studentgrades.coursesid
and studentgrades.averageScore is not null 
and schools.name = 'St. Joe School'           
group by schools.name,  courses.name,standardsgrades.averageScore)
group by grade order by grade;
```